# unable to archive using hadoop archive tool

Tags: hadoop

I'm using following command to archive the files,
"hadoop archive -archiveName ravi.har -p /src /dest"

my /src having two files, ravi.txt and teja.txt with permissions 755.

While trying to execute the above command it is showing error as: 
 The resolved paths set is empty.  Please check whether the srcPaths exist, where srcPaths = [/src]

What is wrong here??

Answer (score 2):

you may need to specify the directories you wanted to archive like

```
hadoop archive -archiveName ravi.har -p /src d1 d2 /dest
```

i am assuming that you have two directories d1 and d2 under /src directory those you want to archive for more detail you can refer [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hadoop_archives.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably your local files. Command excepts hdfs file path, not local.
You may import this files to hdfs using [copyFromLocal](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html#copyFromLocal)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

`hadoop archive -archiveName ravi.har -p / src /dest` 
?